# Javascript created Input box not showing typed text

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am dynamically creating HTML text entry boxes, via JavaScript. They do show up on the webpage, and their border does highlight when I attempt to type into them.

However, nothing shows up in the input box as I type. Nor can I set it's contents via the `innerHTML` attribue.

The input Boxes are positioned absolutely over a canvas.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks so much!

```js
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  //line(40, 50 + i * 42, 1875, 50 + i * 42);

  var inputBox = document.createElement('input');
  inputBox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  inputBox.style.position = 'absolute';
  inputBox.style.top = 142 + i * 42 + 'px';
  inputBox.style.left = '500px';
  inputBox.style.width = '30px';
  inputBox.style.height = '23px';
  inputBox.style.fontSize = '10px';
  inputBox.style.display = 'block';
  // inputBox.innerHTML = 'J';
  inputBox.id.attr = 'attr' + i;

  var parentItem = document.getElementById('canvasForHTML');
  parentItem.appendChild(inputBox);
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasForHTML"></div>
```

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine in the snippet I created from the code you provided. Note that I commented out the `line()` method call, as you didn't include that logic, but it doesn't appear relevant to the issue described. It's possible that the canvas underneath the element is interfering with the UI rendering, but without seeing the actual HTML and CSS involved with that, there's nothing here to diagnose.

Comment: Have you checked that the text color isn't the same as the background color? That has gotten me before (esp. if you've got a dark mode)

Comment: We can't exactly see how to canvas and everything in general is styled - but yes it could be a problem with the canvas. Maybe you can wrap the inputs while still being in the canvas and check the z-index values? Like Rory McCrossan said: we need more code. Otherwise it's just guessing

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code in Codepen and when removing the `line expression` your code works. You can't use innerHTML to set input values - use `value`. I integrated that in the code example below and made small optical adjustments so you can see the result.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var inputBox = document.createElement('input');
  inputBox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  inputBox.style.position = 'absolute';
  inputBox.style.top = 142 + i * 42 + 'px';
  inputBox.style.left = '50px';
  inputBox.style.width = '200px';
  inputBox.style.border = '3px dotted blue';
  inputBox.style.height = '23px';
  inputBox.style.fontSize = '10px';
  inputBox.style.display = 'block';
  inputBox.id.attr = 'attr' + i;
  inputBox.value = 'a predefined value ' + i;

  var parentItem = document.getElementById('canvasForHTML');
  parentItem.appendChild(inputBox);  
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasForHTML"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for investigating. This did help me figure out what was wrong.  I was using the p5.js framework, and was attempting to create the HTML text boxes in their draw() routine, which I think is meant only for their graphic calls.  Once I moved it out of there, the text boxes worked properly. Thanks!